# Allowing multiple processes to connect to a singleton process and invoke method calls or access resources

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, ipc

*Scenario:*

I currently have a class **`MyLoadBalancerSingleton`** that manages access to a cluster of resources (**`resource1`** and **`resource2`**). The class has methods *create(count)* and *delete(count)*. When these methods get called, the load balancer would queue up the request and then processes it FIFO on the resources.

Naturally, there should be only one load balancer running otherwise each they'll all think they have complete control over the resources being managed.

*Here is the problem:*

Multiple users will simultaneously try to access the load balancer from a GUI. Each user will spawn their own GUI via `python gui.py` on the same machine. (They will all ssh into the same machine) As such, each GUI will be running in it's own process. The GUI will then attempt to communicate with the load balancer.

Is it possible to have those multiple GUI processes access only one loadbalancer process and call the load balancer's methods?

I looked into the `multiprocessing` library and it appears that the workflow is opposite to what I want. Using my example it would be: Loadbalancer process spawns 2 GUI processes (child) and then shares the parent resources with the child. In my example, both the GUI and the load balancer are top level processes. (No parent-child relationship)

I suspect that Singleton is not the right word as singletons only work within one process. Maybe run the load balancer as a daemon process and then have those GUI processes connect to it? I tried searching IPC but it just lead me to the `multiprocessing` module which is not what I want. The `distributed, cluster computing modules (dispy)` isn't what I want either. This is strictly processes communicating with each other (IPC?) on the same machine.

Which brings me to my original question:
*Is it possible to allow multiple processes to connect to a singleton process and invoke method calls or access its resources? All processes will be executing on the same machine.*

Fictitious pseudocode:

LoadBalancer.py

```
class MyLoadBalancerSingleton(object):
    def __init__():
        # Singleton instance logic here
        # Resource logic here
    def create(count):
        resource1.create(count)
        resource2.create(count)
    def delete(count):
        resource1.delete(count)
        resource2.delete(count)
```

Gui.py

```
class GUI(object):
    def event_loop():
        # count = Ask for user input
        # process = Locate load balancer process
        # process.create(count)
        # process.delete(count)
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I don't have a Python-specific example easily at hand, but you can do it. There are several kinds of IPC that allow multiple clients (GUIs, in your case) to connect to a single server (your singleton, which yes, would usually be run as a daemon). Here are a few of them:

- Cross-platform: TCP sockets. You'd need your server to allow multiple connections on a single listening socket, and handle them as clients connect (and disconnect). The easiest approach to use across multiple machines, but also the least secure option (no ACLs, etc.).
- Windows-specific: Named pipes. Windows' named pipes, unlike the similarly-named but much less capable feature of POSIX OSes, can allow multiple clients to connect at once. You'd need to create a multiple-instance pipe server. MSDN has good examples of this. I'm not sure what the best way to do it in Python would be, but I know that ActivePython has wrappers for the NT named pipe APIs. The clients only need to be able to open a file (of the form `\\.\pipe\LoadBalancer`). File APIs are used to read from, and write to, the pipes.
- POSIX-only (Linux, BSD, OS X, etc.): Unix domain sockets. The POSIX equivalent of NT's named pipes, they use socket APIs but the endpoint is on the file system (like, `/var/LoadBalanceSocket`) instead of on an IP address/protocol/port tuple.
- Various other things, using stuff like shared memory / memory-mapped files, RPC, COM (on Windows), Grand Central Dispatch (OS X), D-Bus (cross-platform but third-party), and so on. None of them, with the possible exception of GCD, is ideal for the simple case you're talking about here.

Of course, each of these approaches require the server to handle multiple simultaneously-connected clients. The server will need to synchronize across them, and avoid one client blocking the others from being served. You could use multithreading for quick responsiveness and minimal CPU cost while waiting, or polling for a quick-and-dirty solution that avoids multithreading synchronization (mutexes and the like).

Comment: Great answer. It provided overview and capabilities of each option. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, and good luck with your project! Also, welcome to StackOverflow! A quick tip: if you think an answer is good (worth giving recognition to, even if it's not the best possible answer), you can hit the up arrow next to it to increase its visibility. Normally I'd also mention the "accept this answer" checkmark, but you already hit that one.